# AVAudio Player stop working on Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` it is working perfectly on device as well, but after suddenly it stopped working on device while it is still working on the simulator. I don't understand why it stopped working. Please check below code

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlStr];

    self.audioSound = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];

    playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    [self.audioSound replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Comment: Forgive if this isn't what is happening to you, but is the mute switch on your device set to vibrate? Considering you are using the AVPlayer.

Comment: You may have just excluded it, but are you actually playing the new item after replacing the current one? (`[self.audioSound play]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not seeing any code for playing video, like `[player play];`.

Have you written this code?

Comment: oh sheet, at the time of changes by mistake i removed this.... It is working now.. Thanks Thanks....